# Why type error : in <string> requires string as left operand, not list

Tags: python

I'm facing one error in my python script. Please let's me know how can i do for it.

```
import requests import sys import time
url="http://10.10.10.7/dvwa/vulnerabilities/fi/?page=" 
words = ['root','version','crontab']
cookies = {'security' : 'medium','PHPSESSID':'fbd52775729365907b53e763854c5d24'}
f=open('Payloads.txt','r') 
for i in f.readlines():
    ur=requests.get(url+'{}'.format(i),cookies=cookies)
    if words in ur.content.decode("utf-8"):
        print(( ' [Detect LFI]------->   '+'  Payload is  '+str(i)))
            time.sleep(1)
    else:
        print("Not Found LFI Vulnerability")
print ("Scanning....... complete")
```

Error Message:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is with this line:

```
if words in ur.content.decode("utf-8"):
```

`words` is a list and `ur.content.decode("utf-8")` results in a string.  As the error message says, the left hand side of an expression of the form:

```
<left-hand-side> in <string>
```

requires that `<left-hand-side>` be a string, not a list.  Here's an expression that will do what you want to do:

```
if any(s in ur.content.decode("utf-8") for s in words):
```